# How to apply a loop within a tag?

Tags: aem, sightly

I have this such a list:

```
//properties.datas

data-hello="sup"
data-world="w00rld"
```

Can I generate a tag and loop all the data attributes into there? I only understand how to generate multiple HTML tags.

Result:

```
<div data-hello="sup" data-world="w00rld">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a map to `data-sly-attribute` and it will render all corresponding pairs as attributes: `key="value"`. See https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#223-attribute

```
<div data-sly-attribute="${model.datas}">...</div>
```